# Manifest merger failed - android studio error

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, android-manifest, androidx

I changed the name of the package to "com.xxx.xxx" with `Refactor > Rename` and changed the name of the package and application identifiers to`manifest` and `gradle`. Successful synchronization, everything is OK. According to the instructions [delevopers.google Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk) and [delevopers.google Intermediate Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=en) ads built into my application, previously included in the `project structure` **AdMob**. When using gradle, but it cost me to try to run the application on a physical level.

```
Manifest merge error: Attribute application @ appComponentFactory value = (android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml: 22: 18-91
also present in [androidx.core: core: 1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml: 22: 18-86 value = (androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools: replace = "android: appComponentFactory"' to the <application> element in AndroidManifest.xml: 8: 5-27: 19 to override.
```

If you advertise `android.useAndroidX = true` and `android.enableJetifier = true` in the gradle properties, then everything becomes even worse, because my `MainActivity.java` extendit is`AppCompatActivity`, which is not used with the above `gradle` properties (android.useAndroidX = true)

Comment: You have to migrate to androidx.

Comment: post your `build.gradle` file so that we can actually see your dependencies , you seem to have android.support.v4.* files

Comment: build.gradle: http://pastecode.ru/b35114/


`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Google play services [now](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) requires androidx library. You can't use support libraries.

Comment: But i don't use GP Services. My app doesn't need it

Comment: I tried to migrate to AndroidX. After migration, I still get errors when synchronizing with Gradle: https://pastebin.com/0hi84b5N

My app gradle: https://pastebin.com/U8wf9Lh4

Answer (score 0):

It is because in gradle you have to also change it to androidX and check your dependency with this

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}




android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example1.*appname*"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        **testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"**//check this is their or not
    }
```

sometimes we forget to define testInstruement runner

Answer (score 0):

Well since you did not post your `build.gradle` file

I suspect that you have the old android support libraries and you are trying to migrate to AndroidX, According to your error it appears that you should be using this one instead

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
```

of

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
```

And a couple of other files related files in that same manner, now before trying to manually fix the paths of androidx , I would recommend that you update to the latest version of `Android Studio (3.4.2)` and do click `Migrate to AndroidX` inside the refactor menu

[image: Click Migrate to Android X]

Now sometimes, the error might be in the libraries you want to depend to
If that's the case , heres a workaround ...

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'support-v4' // This removes all other versions of `support-v4` if gets duplicated from all the artifacts.
    api project(':your-awesome-library-goes-here')
}
```

also if there is a slight chance that you are using butterknife

```
        android{
.
.
           // Butterknife requires Java 8.
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
.
.
        }
```

Do a sync , if you still see errors ... then try to check for dependencies to see which library is the culprit

```
./gradlew app:androidDependencies
```

Where `app` is your module's name

Cheers

Comment: I tried to follow the suggestion: tools added: `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" in AndroidManifest.xml`, but I got new errors: https://pastebin.com/8qqNK4WP

Comment: Can you add your `build.gradle` file so that we can see what you did to reach there?

Comment: also do try `gradle assemble -info` and let's also see what that says, but I am pretty sure that either your libraries or your `build.gradle` file is still using the `old support libraries` hence the errors

Comment: I just saw your http://pastecode.ru/b35114 and you are still using the *OLD support libraries* as in `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'` , use the androidx ones instead